# Extraño comportamiento de Express.js al sostener ruta

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express

mi problema es que no entiendo porqué cuando en un HTML trato de cargar una imagen como esta:

```html
    <img src="/images/logo.jpg">
```

Mi código busca en el directorio **"public/images"** y también busca en el directorio **"/images"**.

Esta es una muestra del directorio de mi proyecto en donde se centra el "problema".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el código (pongo el resto de las rutas para aclarar la configuración):

```javascript
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.get("/",(req,res)=>{res.sendFile("/public/index.html",{root:__dirname})})
    app.get("/registrarse",(req,res)=>{res.sendFile("/public/registrarse.html",{root:__dirname})})
    app.get("/loguearse",(req,res)=>{res.sendFile("/public/loguearse.html",{root:__dirname})})
    app.get("/miperfil",(req,res)=>{res.sendFile("/public/miperfil.html",{root:__dirname})})
    app.get("/olvidepassword",(req,res)=>{res.sendFile("/public/olvidepassword.html",{root:__dirname})})
    app.get("/cambiarpassword",(req,res)=>{res.sendFile("/public/cambiarpassword.html",{root:__dirname})})

    //La siguiente ruta no devería devolver las imágenes situadas en "/public/images" sin embargo las envia si la encuentra . 
    app.get("/images/:imagen",(req,res)=>{res.sendFile("images/"+req.params.imagen,{root:__dirname})})
```

Como indica el comentario del código, la ruta "/images/:imagen", no debería buscar y enviar  imágenes que están en el directorio "/public/images y sin embargo lo hace. Lo cual no es el comportamiento deseado porque para obtener las imágenes no publicas ("/images"), se verificará el Token posteriormente y el usuario no registrado debe poder acceder al contenido estático.
Espero vuestra ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano.
PD. Más allá del carácter practico, me interesa entender este comportamiento.

Comment: Hola buenas. Lo estás especificando en app.use(express.static('public')).
Echa un vistazo a la documentación:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
Para referirte a esa carpeta de imégenes, prueba con "../images/logo.jpg"

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido. No sabía que se podían especificar varios directorios estáticos. Entonces si cumple el funcionamiento deseado, porque al verificar el Token en la ruta "/images/:imagen" no se negará el contenido publico.